# Typing Numba functions using classes and dictionaries

Tags: python, numba

This is a simplified version of my program:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import types, typed, njit


@njit(signature_or_function=types.unicode_type(types.unicode_type))
def my_func(symbol):
    return "*" + symbol + "*"


@njit
def run_numba(symbols):
    for symbol in symbols:
        result = my_func(symbol=symbol)  # set symbol to be a literal =  "a"
        print(result)

symbols = np.array(["a", "b"], dtype="<U2")
run_numba(symbols)
```

With the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
           ^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/home/me/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/envs/my_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "/home/me/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/envs/my_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of type(CPUDispatcher(<function my_func at 0x7f172e1499e0>)) with parameters (symbol=[unichr x 2])
Known signatures:
 * (unicode_type,) -> unicode_type
During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function my_func at 0x7f172e1499e0>))
During: typing of call at <input> (13)
File "<input>", line 13:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

In the commented line, if I use a string literal in place of the `symbol` variable, it works. How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just omit any signature:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit
def my_func(symbol):
    return "*" + symbol + "*"


@njit
def run_numba(symbols):
    for symbol in symbols:
        result = my_func(symbol=symbol)
        print(result)


symbols = np.array(["a", "b"], dtype="<U2")
run_numba(symbols)
```

---

Prints:

```
*a*
*b*
```

Answer (score 1):

Following answers to [Numba - string types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64807248/numba-string-types), you could do:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import njit, types


# create the required input type
UnicharType = numba.from_dtype(np.dtype("<U2"))

@njit(signature_or_function=types.unicode_type(UnicharType))
def my_func(symbol):
    return "*" + symbol + "*"


@njit
def run_numba(symbols):
    for symbol in symbols:
        result = my_func(symbol=symbol)  # set symbol to be a literal =  "a"
        print(result)

symbols = np.array(["a", "b"], dtype="<U2")
run_numba(symbols)
```